# Static IP for Router set in bridge mode

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, wireless-router

I have two routers

1. Router-A is connected to the internet (Tplink Router)
2. Router-B is connected to Router-A via LAN cable and set to "bridge" mode. (Iball router)

I am able to access the internet on both routers.

The issue is that when I connect to Router-B, it takes longer and I have to reboot the router at times.

what I suspect is happening is the Router-B is slow in assigning IP to a device being connected. (Do let me know if there can be other issues)

What if I set static IPs so the Router-B does not have to think about assigning an Ip.
So my question is where do I go about setting the static IPs in Router-A or Router-B or BOTH.

Comment: It seems you misunderestand what "bridge mode" does - it effectively turns a router into an AP/switch.   Thus you should disable the dhcp server running on router-b and let router-a handle DHCP.  You can set router b up with a static IP address or as a dhcp client.  Also  you really need to provide the router models with the level of help you have asked for.

Comment: ah yes, I checked the DHCP server is turned off, my bad. So I guess the ROUTER-A is doing the ip assigning. ROUTER-A is "TPLink Archer c1200" and ROUTER-B is "iBall baton 150M". The question still remains as to why there is a delay while connecting to ROUTER-B

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely turn off DHCP on router A as this can complicate things, and you should probably assign a static IP address to "router" b if you are going to be using the web UI of the access point at all, otherwise you will have to check what address it has been assigned every time from the main router. As for the delay, it could be a number of things, you might want to check out the configuration of the access point some more. It could be a slow cable, old firmware, router b is set to older 802.11 -- What happens that you have to reboot router so often? just takes indefinite amount of time to connect wirelessly?

Comment: Yes, it takes indefinite time to connect wirelessly or doesnot connect hence I have to reboot. As of now the DHCP server on ROUTER A is on and ROUTER 2 is off. I have assigned a static IP to  ROUTER B, so i can connect to it easily.

Comment: ok, then I would look at the firmware and security for router b. There should be a section in the web interface similar to "firmware upgrade", usually it will have the option to either check online for new firmware from the manufacturer, or upload it yourself from a computer. First check online, and if there is nothing, you can look into custom firmware like [DD-WRT](https://dd-wrt.com). You also might want to check if you are using some outdated or incompatible security standard like WEP, and switch it to WPA2 or WPA. I'm running out of characters, so I'll have to leave it there for now.